# Implement onReceive() when a button in MainActivity is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I've seen various people implement `onReceive()` within their class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. But is there a way to implement `onReceive()` in a different class than `MainActivity`, when a button in pressed in the `MainActivity`? If that's possible, how would I call `onReceive()` when the button is pressed? I have a receiver implemented in my `AndroidManifest` file as well, so will that be triggered also, when the button is pressed and `onReceive()` is called?

MainActivity class -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button activateButton;
LocationManager mManager;
AlertDialog.Builder box;
BroadcastReceiver b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activate);
    activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                DialogBox();
        }
    });

}

protected void DialogBox() {
    box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    box.setTitle("Reject incoming calls?").
            setMessage("On activation, your phone will reject all incoming calls").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
                    MainActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = box.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

RejectCall class -

```
public class RejectCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("RejectClass", "Triggered");
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.scimet.admin.driveon" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".RejectCall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I've defined an interface for ITelephony as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement dialog to save preferences for rejecting the calls:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    protected void DialogBox() {
        box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        box.setTitle("Reject incoming calls?").
                setMessage("On activation, your phone will reject all incoming calls").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         preferences.edit().putBoolean(PREF_REJECT_CALLS, true).commit();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 preferences.edit().putBoolean(PREF_REJECT_CALLS, false).commit();                
                 dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = box.create();
        alert.show();

    }



public class RejectCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // If the value in preferences is false, do not reject the calls
    if(!preferences.getBoolean(PREF_REJECT_CALLS, false)){
       return;
    }

    Log.i("RejectClass", "Triggered");
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, my phone just crashes on implementing that way. The phone restarts. I'll edit the description and post my code.

Comment: See my edit, you need to save preferences to switch rejecting on or off. The Broadcast is sent by System when the call is received.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be 'preferences.edit().putBoolean("PREF_REJECT_CALLS", true).commit();' I'm sorry, I could be totally wrong. Also, how does this save preference?

Comment: Also, I used SharedPreferences instead. Is there a problem? That's probably why I had to use putBoolean()

Comment: You are right, its putBoolean and you can use SharedPreferences. I was writing from memory. I will edit the post.

Comment: The call doesn't get rejected at all. What could be the problem. On phone ringing, the activity stops, should that not be happening if I want the call to be rejected?

Comment: Is your RejectCall class placed in com.scimet.admin.driveon?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62374/discussion-between-slay-and-janknotek).

Comment: Do you see the log message "Triggered"? If yes, the problem can be in private method you are using for ending the call. I have implemented it in Android 4.0 and it was working there. But it could be changed in later versions of Android OS.